# Error in Mean shift Clustering when input is distance matrix

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

When i run the following code:

```
library(fossil)
df    <- data.frame(long,lat)
dist  <- earth.dist(df, dist=F) #calculating distance matrix
library(LPCM)
ms(dist,0.43,scaled=TRUE,iter=100,plotms=1)
```

I get an error:

```
Error in if (th[j] < thresh) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I have passed every input which is needed to run mean shift clustering. Why am I getting this error?
How to tell `ms` that input is distance matrix not the data matrix?

```
    head(df)
      long      lat
1 116.3313 39.97575
2 116.3315 39.97562
3 116.3319 39.97550
4 116.3321 39.97545
5 116.3324 39.97550
6 116.3327 39.97548
```

Comment: Try passing in `na.rm = TRUE` as another argument to `ms`.

Comment: @Scott Ritchie tried,Not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ms(dist,0.43,scaled=TRUE,iter=100,plotms=1,na.rm=TRUE)
```

give the command **traceback()** right after the error. That will let you figure out what line of your code is causing the error. Look at whether anything is missing or 0 that you don't expect to be in that iteration.

Comment: traceback() won't tell anything.It will tell that error is occurring in ms(dist,0.43,scaled=TRUE,iter=100,plotms=1,na.rm=TRUE)

Answer (score 0):

Since the `ms` function doesn't appear to be able to handle missing values, you're going to have to remove them from your dataframe:

```
df <- df[apply(df, 1, function(x) !any(is.na(x))),]
dist  <- earth.dist(df, dist=F) #calculating distance matrix
library(LPCM)
ms(dist,0.43,scaled=TRUE,iter=100,plotms=1)
```

Comment: dist is a distance matrix so all the diagonal elements are zero. There are no missing values in df but could be in dist. I used above code to remove them. Still getting the same error

Comment: can you update your question with the output from `head(df)` so we have some data to work with?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood mean-shift,

### Mean-Shift cannot be used with a precomputed distance matrix

Because it needs to *move points*, and compute distances from the *moved* location. How are you going to precompute these distances?

This is essentially the same as for k-means, which also needs distances to the means.

Comment: Yes I guess that is right . I have tried k-means and PAM then I uses dbscan. Till now dbscan is best but in dbscan also clusters are not way I wanted.

Comment: Definitly try complete-link clustering, which from your previous question seemed best. But unless you have a lot of data near the -180+180 degree line, mean-shift in ELKI should work okay for you, it _can_ use geodetic distance. Just computing the mean will fail badly near the date line there, too. But as you are interested in a maximum diameter for your clusters, this just cries for "complete linkage".

Comment: Are there any tutorials for ELKI. I couldn't find any

Comment: Searching for "ELKI Tutorial" yields results for me. But obviously it's not as old or big as R in the end... but most R packages don't come with a tutorial either.